# How to add a case-insensitive unique constraint in a SequelizeJS Model when using Postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
var Model = sequelize.define('Company', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true
  }
}
```

In the above example, unique: true is case sensitive. It allows both "sample" and "Sample" to be saved in the db. Is there a built-in way to do this in sequelize without having to write a custom validator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a functional unique index as seen here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c57a8ecec259afdc4f4caafc5d0e92eb@mitre.org

```
var Model = sequelize.define('Company', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, 
{
  indexes: [
    { 
      unique: true,   
      name: 'unique_name',  
      fields: [sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('name'))]   
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! If that is violated, will sequelize throw a Sequelize.ValidationError like other sequelize validators?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco Validation happens before the data is sent to the database, so I wouldn't expect so. Instead the save() function (or update() etc) will fail.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ah. Makes sense since this unique index will be done on the database level. So I guess if I add this unique index, I still need to write a custom case-insensitive unique validator. Thanks!

Comment: @Jan Aagaard Meier - I tried your suggestion above. But for some reason, it still allows both "sample" and "Sample" to be saved in the db. Any idea why? Hmm. Should I convert strings to lower case before I save them to db?

Comment: It should work out of the box - do you see a unique index `lower(name)` created in the log? Are you perhaps using an old version of sequelize, I believe `indexes` was introduced somewhere in 2.0

Comment: Woops, I forgot the most important part - that the index should actually be unique. Post updated

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier It works now after I added unique: true in the index. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Is there supposed to be a `:` after `fields`?

Comment: @Noah Yes - Edited

Comment: I can't make a single character edit but there is a missing brace in the fields definition. `[sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('name'))]`

Answer (score 1):

01AUG2022 update. I stumbled across this while trying to solve the same problem and I come with good news! As long as you're using Postgres or SQLite you can set your data type to `type: DataTypes.CITEXT` and your values will retain their case in the database while also giving a Validation error if you try to add another entry regardless of case.

TLDR: `testuser` and `TestUser` will throw a validation error if the column type is `CITEXT`.